# Error: You do not own this site, Google Search Console API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-search-console

I keep receiving the error:

> 'Error: You do not own this site, or the inspected URL is not part of this property.'

when trying to inspect a URL using the Google Search Console API although I am the verified owner of the domain.

I am able to list sites with my credentials without issue.

My code:

```
app.get("/inspecturl", (req, res) => {
  searchconsole.urlInspection.index.inspect(
    {
      siteUrl: "sc-domain:my-domain.co.uk",
      inspectionUrl: "www.my-domain.co.uk",
    },
    (err, response) => {
      if (err) return res.status(500).send(`Error: ${err}`);
      res.send(response.data);
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, when inspecting the root domain, the inspectionUrl provided must end with a '/'

Comment: Which needs the trailing slash, the `siteURL`, the `inspectionUrl`, or both?

Comment: I'd think that the `inspectionUrl` would also need to start with `https://`.

Comment: "the inspectionUrl provided must end with a '/'"

Answer (score 0):

2024 Update

Was getting the same error, resolved it by adding trailing slash to the siteUrl property.

From :

```
{
inspectionUrl: "https://google.com/mypage/",
siteUrl: "https://www.google.com",
languageCode: "en-US",
}
```

To (notice added a trailing slash to the siteUrl)

```
{
inspectionUrl: "https://google.com/mypage/",
siteUrl: "https://www.google.com/",
languageCode: "en-US",
}
```